# Session.request and 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, serialization, django-forms, django-sessions, django-serializer

I try to improve my Django knowledge (I'm a beginner) by developing a Django ecommerce website.
I'd like to have two types of cart, one named cart and this other one named composed_cart.
I have an error with the composed_cart.
I came accross the following error when I try to display the cart: `Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable`

For my add to composed_cart class, I use the following code:

composed_cart.py:

```
class ComposedCart(object):
def __init__(self, request):
    self.session = request.session
    composed_cart = self.session.get('composed_cart')

    if not composed_cart:
        composed_cart = self.session['composed_cart'] = {}
    self.composed_cart = composed_cart

def add_composed(self, product, quantity=1):
    product_id = str(product.id)

    if product_id not in self.composed_cart:
        self.composed_cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 1,'price': str(product.prix_unitaire), 'tva': str(product.taux_TVA.taux_applicable)}

    else:
        self.composed_cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity #Ajoute +1 à la quantité et met à jour le dictionnaire contenant la quantité. += signifie ajoute à la valeur initiale de quantité.

    self.save()

def save(self):
    self.session['composed_cart'] = self.composed_cart
    self.session.modified = True


def remove(self, product): #Supprimer le produit, quelque soit la quantité.
    product_id = str(product.id)

    if product_id in self.composed_cart:
        del self.composed_cart[product_id]
    self.save()

def remove_one(self, product, quantity=1): #Méthode permettant de supprimer une unité du produit.
    product_id = str(product.id)

    if product_id in self.composed_cart: #Si le produit est dans le panier
        if self.composed_cart[product_id]['quantity'] > 1: #Et si la quantité de ce produit est supérieure à 1
            self.composed_cart[product_id]['quantity'] -= quantity #On enlève la quantité par défaut, d'est à dire 1.
        else:
            del self.composed_cart[product_id] #Si la quantité du produit est égale à 1 alors et que l'on veut enlever une unité, cela veut dire que l'on supprimer le produit.
    self.save()


def __iter__(self):

    product_ids = self.composed_cart.keys() #Sélectionne les différentes clés du dictionnaires, dans notre cas l'id du produit, la quantité, le prix.

    products = Article.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids) #On filtre sur les IDs présents dans le dictionnaire du panier.

    for product in products:
        self.composed_cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

    for item in self.composed_cart.values():
        item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
        item['tva'] = Decimal(item['tva'])
        item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
        item['total_item_tva'] = item['total_price'] - item['total_price'] / item['tva'] #Calcul du total de TVA par article.
        yield item

def __len__(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.composed_cart.values())

def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.composed_cart.values())

def get_total_tva(self):
    return sum(round(Decimal(item['total_item_tva']),2) for item in self.composed_cart.values()) #Calcul de la TVA, round(X,2), permet d'arrondir à 2 décimales après la virgule le montant de la TVA

def get_sub_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.composed_cart.values()) - sum(round(Decimal(item['total_item_tva']),2) for item in self.composed_cart.values())

def clear(self):
    del self.session['composed_cart']
    self.session.modified = True
```

My cart.py:

```
class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get('cart')

        if not cart:
            cart = self.session['cart'] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1):
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 1,'price': str(product.prix_unitaire), 'tva': str(product.taux_TVA.taux_applicable)}

        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity #Ajoute +1 à la quantité et met à jour le dictionnaire contenant la quantité. += signifie ajoute à la valeur initiale de quantité.

        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session['cart'] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True


    def remove(self, product): #Supprimer le produit, quelque soit la quantité.
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

    def remove_one(self, product, quantity=1): #Méthode permettant de supprimer une unité du produit.
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id in self.cart: #Si le produit est dans le panier
            if self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] > 1: #Et si la quantité de ce produit est supérieure à 1
                self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] -= quantity #On enlève la quantité par défaut, d'est à dire 1.
            else:
                del self.cart[product_id] #Si la quantité du produit est égale à 1 alors et que l'on veut enlever une unité, cela veut dire que l'on supprimer le produit.
        self.save()


    def __iter__(self):

        product_ids = self.cart.keys() #Sélectionne les différentes clés du dictionnaires, dans notre cas l'id du produit, la quantité, le prix.

        products = Article.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids) #On filtre sur les IDs présents dans le dictionnaire du panier.

        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['tva'] = Decimal(item['tva'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            item['total_item_tva'] = item['total_price'] - item['total_price'] / item['tva'] #Calcul du total de TVA par article.
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_tva(self):
        return sum(round(Decimal(item['total_item_tva']),2) for item in self.cart.values()) #Calcul de la TVA, round(X,2), permet d'arrondir à 2 décimales après la virgule le montant de la TVA

    def get_sub_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values()) - sum(round(Decimal(item['total_item_tva']),2) for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session['cart']
        self.session.modified = True
```

My view is this one for adding product:

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Article, id=product_id)
    #Si le produit ajouté au panier est un article simple sans composition, alors on l'ajoute directement au panier.
    if product.article_composer == False:
        cart = Cart(request)
        form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            next = cd['next'] # Permet d'enregistrer la page précédente et d'y retourner une fois la quantité ajoutée dans le panier.
            cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next) # Redirection vers la page d'où le produit a été ajouté.

    #Si l'article que l'on ajoute au panier sert à composer alors on utilise la méthode permettant de composer un article.
    else:
        composed_cart = ComposedCart(request)
        form = ComposedCartForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            next = cd['next'] # Permet d'enregistrer la page précédente et d'y retourner une fois la quantité ajoutée dans le panier.
            composed_cart.add_composed(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

And for displaying my cart:

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    composed_cart = ComposedCart(request)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request, 'panier/panier.html', locals())
```

I don't undestand why i get a TypeError. Do you have any ideas? How can i improve my code to get rid off this error?

Thanks in advance

Singertwist

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is `locals()` that you are sending over to the `paneer.html`.

`locals()` is a dictionary of everything in your current namespace which includes complex objects that cannot be serialized (i.e. converted into simple objects such as integer or string).

In order to fix this, try to change it to something simple:

```
return render(request, 'panier/panier.html', {'test': 'value'})
```

If it works, or gives another error, change it to what you need.

The error says that some of the fields are not JSON serializable. The simplest solution would be something like this:

```
cart = {
    'product_id': cart.product_id,
    ... 
}

composed_cart = {
    'id': composed_cart.id,
    ...
}

return render(request, 'panier/panier.html', {'cart': cart, 'composed_cart': composed_cart})
```

That is, manually serialize your objects and choosing the fields that you need in the template.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer,
But I get the same error with the following code:
return render(request, 'panier/panier.html', {'cart': cart, 'composed_cart':composed_cart})

Comment: @singertwist can you try with just `{'test': 'value'}`?

Comment: i tried {'test': 'value'}, i don't have any error. I can display the page (without any data).
I did several other tests for trying to understand the problem.
As I mentioned above, I have two carts, Cart and Composed_Cart
These carts use the same code, except the session request which are:
- for the composed_cart: composed_cart = self.session['composed_cart']
- for the cart:  cart = self.session['cart'] 
When I add a product to the cart.py, and then a different product to a composed_cart it works.
But when, i only add a product to my composed_cart, it doesn't work (Type error).